# How to speed up loading DTD through DOCTYPE

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to load a number of xhtml files that have this at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Each file will be loaded into a separate System.Xml.XmlDocument. Because of the DOCTYPE declaration they take a very long time to load. I tried setting XmlResolver = null, but then I get XmlException thrown because I have invalid entities (e.g., ”). So I thought I could download the DTD just for the first XmlDocument and in some way reuse it for the subsequent XmlDocuments (and thus avoid the performance hit), but I have no idea how to do this.

I'm using .Net 3.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be able to resolve this resolver issue using [`XmlPreloadedResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221694(v=VS.95).aspx).  However, I'm having some difficulty getting it working myself.  It looks like XHTML 1.0 would be easier to support since it is a "known" DTD: [`XmlKnownDtds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.resolvers.xmlknowndtds(v=VS.95).aspx) while XHTML 1.1 isn't currently "known" which means you'll have to reload a bunch of URIs.

For example:

```
XmlPreloadedResolver xmlPreloadedResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver(XmlKnownDtds.Xhtml10);
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml11.dtd"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-framework-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-framework-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-text-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-text-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-hypertext-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-hypertext-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-list-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-list-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-edit-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-edit-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-bdo-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-bdo-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/xhtml-ruby-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-ruby-1.mod"));
xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-pres-1.mod"), File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\xhtml-pres-1.mod"));
// TODO: Add other modules here (see the xhtml11.dtd for the full list)
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.XmlResolver = xmlPreloadedResolver;
xmlDocument.Load("D:\\doc1.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, but XmlPreloadedResolver is .Net 4 only :-(. I'm on 3.5.

Comment: You could create your own derivation of `XmlResolver` that does fundamentally the same thing.

Comment: thanks this is what I have done, using the example here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/HTML2XHTML.aspx?display=Print.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Framework 3.5 and below, it might have been possible to use the `XmlUrlResolver`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646763/1149773). However, this approach downloads the DTDs from the W3C website at runtime, which is not a good idea, not least because W3C seems to be currently blocking such requests. The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682526/1149773) suggests caching the DTDs as embedded resources in the assembly, similar to your [HTML2XHTML](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/HTML2XHTML.aspx).

For other readers using .NET Framework 4.0 and above, you could use `XmlPreloadedResolver`, as suggested [by Daniel Renshaw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733479/1149773), which supports XHTML 1.0. To support XHTML 1.1, you could simplify your implementation by using the flattened version of the DTD, available at [xhtml11-flat.dtd](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11-flat.dtd) on the W3C website. I define an extension method for this purpose:

```
public static class XmlPreloadedResolverExtensions
{
    private const string Xhtml11DtdPublicId = "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN";
    private const string Xhtml11DtdSystemId = "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd";

    public static void AddXhtml11(this XmlPreloadedResolver resolver, bool @override = false)
    {
        Add(resolver, new Uri(Xhtml11DtdPublicId, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), ManifestResources.xhtml11_flat_dtd, @override);
        Add(resolver, new Uri(Xhtml11DtdSystemId, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), ManifestResources.xhtml11_flat_dtd, @override);
    }

    public static bool Add(this XmlPreloadedResolver resolver, Uri uri, Stream value, bool @override)
    {
        if (@override || !resolver.PreloadedUris.Contains(uri))
        {
            resolver.Add(uri, value);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This could then be used like ordinary `XmlResolver` instances:

```
var xmlResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver();
xmlResolver.AddXhtml11();

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
settings.XmlResolver = xmlResolver;

XDocument document;
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(input, settings))
    document = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
```