# Parsing XHTML with DTD using XDocument

Tags: xhtml, windows-phone-7, dtd, linq-to-xml

I need to get plain text from XHTML documents.

I am sure I already read somewhere here, that XDocument on WP7 does not support DTD. I cannot find it though. Well, when I try to parse XHTML with DTD using XDocument, it throws NotSuportedException. Last call in stacktrace is at `System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()`.

That is exactly same even if I try to use some dummy XmlResolver - it doesn't really get called. (following answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645767/how-do-i-resolve-entities-when-loading-into-an-xdocument)).

So I assume that WP7 **really** doesn't support it.

Well, I **need** to parse XHTML docs. So far I came up with two (more or less real) solutions:
I can do that if I remove that DTD declaration. But, there can be some *character entity* in the XHTML, and then exception is thrown if that *character entity* is not one of the *predefined XML entity*.
So that solution works only for some XHTMLs.

I thought of using Regex. It is quite easy to remove all the html tags, but the 'entity problem' remains as I don't think it is real/good solution to do replace for all entities.

Anyone faced/solved this? Can you give me some advice or correct me if I am wrong on something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML Agility pack is a library for parsing html document, as claimed on the forum, it has a version for WP7

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/225113

Comment: Just tried that and it works great! Thank you very much! One line of code solved my problem: `var text = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize( htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Element("html").Element("body").InnerText);`