# Is XDocument.Parse different in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am running the exact same code in a WP7 application and a C# 3.5 application. The WP7 application throws a `NotSupportedException` upon calling `XDocument.Parse()` while the C# 3.5 application parses the XML with no problems. Below is the code used:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadThreadsComplete);
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/40568/", UriKind.Absolute));

...

private static void DownloadThreadsComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? It's strange that it is failing when trying to parse an SC2 forum when a WoW forum works just fine (http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/984270/).

**Edit:**

The exception message is "NotSupportedException". Here's the full stack trace:

```
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text)
   at SC2ForumReader.Pages.ForumViewerPage.DownloadThreadsComplete(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

**Edit2:**

I've done what was suggested and have looked at the output of the 2 different requests. Additionally in my 3.5 client application I forced the user-agent to be the same as it is in the WP7 emulator to ensure it's not the user-agent causing the issue.

Here's the doctype declaration copied from Visual Studio:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">`

The doctypes are the same in each document but there are a few discrepancies in the files that stand out (it looks like there are a few extra characters inserted on the 3.5 side):

WP7 Emulator: `StarCraft II`

3.5 Application: `StarCraftÂ II`

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, including the full message of the exception.

Comment: Just note that some servers change the output based on the user agent - in this case a mobile browser.

Comment: @Jon added the stack trace.

@BuildStarted Hmm, good thought. I tried comparing the string being outputted from the 2 requests and at a quick glance there looks to be a few encoding differences in the two strings. I'll try changing the user agent and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @johnhforrest: As BuildStarted mentioned, it's possible that the data is different. It's probably worth looking at the text in the debugger and posting the first few lines (it looks like it's the doctype declaration causing a problem here).

Comment: Ok, just spent some time comparing the output based on user-agent and it doesn't seem to make a difference in this case. There are weird characters being shown on the 3.5 application side that aren't showing up when the request is performed in the WP7 emulator even with the same user-agent.

Comment: It does not look like it's supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316078/parsing-xhtml-with-dtd-using-xdocument

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that XDocument.Parse enables DTD processing (which is normally disabled by default on a XmlTextReader) yet it does not supply a resolver.  Try this code instead:

```
private static void DownloadThreadsComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc;
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(e.Result), settings))
    {
         doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    }

    // Do stuff with doc
}
```

OR:-

```
private static void DownloadThreadsComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc;
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    settings.XmlResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver(XmlKnownDtds.Xhtml10);

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(e.Result), settings))
    {
         doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    }

    // Do stuff with doc
}
```

Comment: The first example does indeed solve the parsing issue (after wrapping e.Result in a MemoryStream to solve a compilation error) but I wasn't able to build the second example in the WP7 environment, I don't think they have support for the XmlPreloadedResolver. Any idea why Silverlight apps don't like DTDs?

Comment: Actually looks like all the info is here on the reasoning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189013(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @johnhforrest: You need to reference the System.Xml.Utils dll to get the XmlPreloadedResolver.   I'll adjust my answer shortly to solve the bugs, I wouldn't use a MemoryStream, I would use a `StringReader` instead.