# Parse XHTML document with undefined entity

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xhtml

While coding with Python, if I had to load XHTML document with undefined entity, I would create a parser and update entity dict (i.e. `nbsp`):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.entity['nbsp'] = '&#x00A0;'
tree = ET.parse(opener.open(url), parser=parser)
```

With VB.Net I tried to parse XHTML document as Linq XDocument:

```
Dim x As XDocument = XDocument.Load(url)
```

which raised XmlException:

> Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'

Googling around I couldn't find any example how to update entity table or use simple means to be able to parse XHTML document with undefined entity.

How to solve this apparently simple problem?

Comment: Does `XDocument.Load` also read the table of entities in the DTD?

Comment: By default no, I'll need to use XmlReader and enable DTDProcessing for XDocument. But I need to add just this entity to the parser, without request to w3c, or storing DTD for XHTML locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity resolution is done by the underlying parser which is here a standard `XmlReader` (or `XmlTextReader`).

Officially, you're supposed to declare entities in DTDs (see Oleg's answer here: [Problem with XHTML entities](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bdcdba9-2319-43f9-874b-92cc580feea9/problem-with-xhtml-entities)), or load DTDs dynamically into your documents. There are some examples here on SO like this: [How do I resolve entities when loading into an XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645767/how-do-i-resolve-entities-when-loading-into-an-xdocument)

What you can also do is create a hacky `XmlTextReader` derived class that returns `Text` nodes when entities are detected, based on a dictionary, like I demonstrate here in the following sample code:

```
using (XmlTextReaderWithEntities reader = new XmlTextReaderWithEntities(MyXmlFile))
{
    reader.AddEntity("nbsp", "\u00A0");
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}

...

public class XmlTextReaderWithEntities : XmlTextReader
{
    private string _nextEntity;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _entities = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // NOTE: override other constructors for completeness
    public XmlTextReaderWithEntities(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
    }

    public void AddEntity(string entity, string value)
    {
        _entities[entity] = value;
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        if (_nextEntity != null)
            return true;

        return base.Read();
    }

    public override XmlNodeType NodeType
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nextEntity != null)
                return XmlNodeType.Text;

            return base.NodeType;
        }
    }

    public override string Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nextEntity != null)
            {
                string value = _nextEntity;
                _nextEntity = null;
                return value;
            }
            return base.Value;
        }
    }

    public override void ResolveEntity()
    {
        // if not found, return the string as is
        if (!_entities.TryGetValue(LocalName, out _nextEntity))
        {
            _nextEntity = "&" + LocalName + ";";
        }
        // NOTE: we don't use base here. Depends on the scenario
    }
}
```

This approach works in simple scenarios, but you may need to override some other stuff for completeness.

PS: sorry it's in C#, you'll have to adapt to VB.NET :)

Comment: Thanks for your subclassing solution, it worked great for me :) Only thing I additionally add was `reader.XmlResolver = Nothing` before loading XDocument, as without it XmlTextReader is set to pull DTDs from W3C.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this, but you could create a `XmlParserContext` object with required entity declarations as `internalSubset`. Pass that context to `XmlTextReader` in the constructor and create the `XDocument` object by loading the reader. In MSDN there already is a simple looking [example code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b28yfx0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) in VB for using a pre-defined entity.

Comment: This looked easy, but it seems it only works on xmlFragments, and I couldn't find my way with XHTML document from url.

Answer (score 0):

in this case i suppose your taking about of a page on the web so you may use html agility pack which could met your need.

I use xpath, element and more other stuff.It will very usefull to search into an html page etc.

You may find documentation here : [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use special package to parse XHTML, and then I don't want to parse HTML DOM but XML.

Comment: may you let me an idea about xml is?

Comment: It's an object not as expensive as HTML DOM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_tree

Comment: Hi theta :D i know what is an xml, i did the wrong  question :) i'm sorry but sometimes i think in italian and i write as per italian grammar language sorry