# Handling unknown entities when parsing XML with XDocument in a PCL

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, portable-class-library

I am trying to load an XHTML 1.1 document using `XDocument` (LINQ-to-XML) in a portable class library, but am receiving an exception where it can't parse the entities:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 10, position 23.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleGeneralEntityReference(String name, Boolean isInAttributeValue, Boolean pushFakeEntityIfNullResolver, Int32 entityStartLinePos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
   at ShatteredTemple.EpubTweaker.EpubTweaker.LoadXDocumentFromZipFile(ZipFile epub, ZipEntry zipEntry) in [path omitted]\EpubTweaker.cs:line 159
```

(SO wouldn't let me post that in `<pre>` tags - apologies for the faux code formatting.)

Normally I would try embedding the DTD per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645767/how-do-i-resolve-entities-when-loading-into-an-xdocument). However, that requires creating a custom `XmlResolver`, which does not seem to be available to a PCL.

Using `XmlReaderSettings` to try to disable `CheckCharacters` and `DtdProcessing` doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions for how I can handle "unknown" entities when parsing XML inside a PCL? I'd prefer to keep using LINQ-to-XML/`XDocument`, but am potentially open to other XML parsers, as long as they can add an XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`) to the document if one is missing.

Comment: The error says it is on line 10 (not line 1) : 'nbsp'. Line 10, position 23

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with my question. Yes, the offending entity is on line 10 of the XHTML file. But it's not something that needs to be "fixed" in the XHTML - it's a perfectly valid XHTML 1.1 input, but XDocument is failing to parse it because it can't load the DTD.

Comment: That is what I thought but didn't want to jump to any conclusion.  The Net library doesn't work with xml 1.1 (only 1,0).  Posting the exception in tis case leads to the conclusion that there is an error with the xml.  I would still double check with an one-line xml checker to make sure the xml is valid.

Comment: Out of the box, no, it doesn't. If you're using the full framework, you can use a custom XmlResolver to support it, per the question I linked to. But since that doesn't seem to be available in a PCL... I thought I'd ask this question to see if I'm missing any available PCL-compatible alternatives.

Comment: @jdweng this isn't *XML* 1.1, it's *XHTML* 1.1.  XHTML is still XML 1.0.  The error here is pretty common as the XHTML DTDs define various entities like `nbsp`.