# AngleSharp: How to parse XML with XHTML-entities?

Tags: c#, .net-core, anglesharp

I've got XML to parse that mostly looks like XHTML, but according to the docs should be XML, looking like XHTML.

So I resort to **AngleSharp.XML** to parse it. But I already fail to parse the simplest input:

```
<p>Ma&szlig;nahmen</p>
```

This is the code I use for parsing:

```cs
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(new LoaderOptions 
    { 
        IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true 
    }).WithCss().WithXml();

var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

var xml = @"<xml><p>Ma&szlig;nahmen</p></xml>";

var xmlParser = new XmlParser(new XmlParserOptions(), context);
var xmlDoc = xmlParser.ParseDocument(xml);
```

And this is the resulting error:

Message:

> Test method TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestParseEntity threw exception:
> AngleSharp.Xml.Parser.XmlParseException: Error while parsing the provided XML document.

Stack Trace:

```cs
XmlTokenizer.CharacterReference()
XmlTokenizer.DataText(Char c)
XmlTokenizer.Data(Char c)
XmlTokenizer.Get()
XmlDomBuilder.Parse(XmlParserOptions options)
XmlParser.Parse(XmlDocument document)
XmlParser.ParseDocument(String source)
```

What's wrong with my configuration? How can it properly detect the `&szlig;`? Do I need to somehow add DTD references? Do those get resolved automatically or do I have to implement this (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646763/56658))?

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this ticket](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/442) and reading through the code the answer seems quite simple. The configuration can be filled with an `HtmlEntityResolver` which will take over the job and is much more potent than the `XmlEntityResolver` which was used before:

```
var config = Configuration.Default.With(HtmlEntityProvider.Resolver).WithDefaultLoader(new LoaderOptions { IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true}).WithCss().WithXml();
```